# Proxy in boot2docker running containers to run on port 80 and a custom host name

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I'm using `boot2docker` to setup different Docker containers on OSX. However the URLs for the applications running in these Docker containers are accessible through the IP and port e.g. `http://192.168.59.103:8080`

Since the applications I'm working on are configured to run with a web server called Pow and URLs like `htp://myproject.dev`, I'm having trouble migration to Docker for my local development environment.

So how can I point a host name like `htp://myproject.dev:80` to my Docker container `http://192.168.59.103:8080`? I'm already using another host name defined in my `/etc/hosts` file but I don't know what to do about the port.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows, but putting an entry into the system's hosts file did work for me. I included a line like this:

```
192.168.59.103 myproject.dev
```

and I could  go to http://myproject.dev instead of http://192.168.59.103.

In theory this should also work on OSX, instructions on how to edit the hosts file there can, for example, be found here: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks ikkjo. I should have made my question clearer. My problem is the port. How can I redirect requests from 192.168.59.103:8080 to myproject.dev:80

Comment: Maybe the answers here help http://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x/673551#673551? One person is using a hosts file together with ifconfig to achieve port mapping and the accepted answer uses ifconfig and ipfw. As I said, I am not on Mac so I cannot try it out myself.

Comment: Thanks again ikkjo. That solution looks very promising, I'm gonna give it a try now.